# How to display a form answer if it matches the answer in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I've been trying to learn php and to practice, I made an array of Family Guy characters based off the last name. Then I tried asking a question in the form and I wanted the code to check the array to see if it matches the correct answer in the array. I'm still very new to PHP, this is really just a learning experience. The code looks like this...

```
<?php
$families = array(
"Griffin" => array(
"Peter",
"Louis",
"Chris",
"Stewie",
"Meg"
),
"Quagmire" => array(
"Glen"
),
"Brown" => array(
"Cleveland",
"Loretta",
"Junior"
)
);

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Which of these Family Guy Characters is part of the Griffin family?
<form action = "familyguyquestions.php" method = 'post'>
A: <input type = "radio" name = "cleveland">Cleveland
B: <input type = "radio" name = "glenn">Glenn
C: <input type = "radio" name = "meg">Meg
D: <input type = "radio" name = "quagmire">Quagmire
<input type = "submit" name = "submitQuestion">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this:

- send the form to your php, check the answer and render a page displaying whether the answer is good or not
- make an AJAX request to server and return a JSON containing whether the answer is correct or not and update the DOM

As for the how to send the data, you should have the same `name` attribute on your radio buttons and a hidden input to know what array to look into and also the array key (since you have an array of arrays).

html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Which of these Family Guy Characters is part of the Griffin family?
<form action = "familyguyquestions.php" method = 'post'>
<input type="hidden" value="families" name="what_array" />
<input type="hidden" value="Griffin" name="what_array_key" />
A: <input type = "radio" name="answer" value = "cleveland">Cleveland
B: <input type = "radio" name="answer" value = "glenn">Glenn
C: <input type = "radio" name="answer" value = "meg">Meg
D: <input type = "radio" name="answer" value = "quagmire">Quagmire
<input type = "submit" name = "submitQuestion">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
if (false == isset($_POST['what_array'])) {
    // No array here, return an error
}
if (false == isset($_POST['what_array_key'])) {
    // No key here, return an error
}
if (false == isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    // No answer, return error
}

$the_array = $_POST['what_array'];
$the_array_key = $_POST['what_array_key'];
$the_answer = $_POST['answer'];

$the_array = ($$the_array);
if (false == isset($the_array)) {
    // Another array to look into was set, return error
}

if (true == in_array($the_answer, $the_array[$the_array_key])) {
    // Here the answer is ok
} else {
    // Wrong answer
}
```

Notice double dollar sign on `$$the_array`. This is how you get a variable by string. If `$the_array` is 'families', `$$the_array` will be the actual array in which you want to look.

[example](http://ideone.com/myMsrI)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with in_array function like this:

```
if (in_array($_POST['answer'], $families['Griffin'])) 
{
 // true 
}   else
{
// false
}
```

Also you need to set proper name to your radio buttons which is:

```
A: <input type = "radio" name = "answer" value="Cleveland">Cleveland
B: <input type = "radio" name = "answer" value="Glenn">Glenn
C: <input type = "radio" name = "answer" value="Meg">Meg
D: <input type = "radio" name = "answer" value="Quagmire">Quagmire
```

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons are incorrectly structured. They should all have the same `name`, e.g. `name="guess"`, and each of the character names should be in the value, e.g. `value="cleveland"`.

Then it's a simple matter of doing:

```
if (isset($families['Griffn'][$_POST['guess']]) {
   ... correct ...
} else {
   ... wrong ...
}
```

But note that PHP array keys are CASE-SENSITIVE. You'd have to have the exact SAME name in the form as you do in the array:

```
<input type="radio" name="guess" value="Cleveland"> This is correct
<input type="radio" name="guess" value="cleveland"> Incorrect, lower case c on the name.
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me. I fixed my radio buttons including the case sensitive values but it still didn't work. I used... if(isset($families['Griffin'][$_POST['guess']])){
 echo "Correct";
}
else{
 echo "Wrong";
}